# Does it returns the number of rows?

Tags: python, mysql

This is my MySQL database:

```
create table 'blogs' (
    'id' int(10) primary key auto_increment,
    'title' varchar(29) not null,
    'text' varchar(500) not null
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8mb4;
```

I use PyMySQL to connect it and then I do this:

```
cur = connection.cursor().execute('select title, text from blogs order by id desc')

entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

It raised this:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'`

I try `type(cur)` and obviously I got `int`

I try `print(cur)` and I got `0`

After `insert blogs(title,text) values ('222','qwqwqwq');` `print(cur)`=`1`

After `insert blogs(title,text) values ('333','qwqw222');` `print(cur)`=`2`

Is `cur` the rows of `blogs`?

And how I could achieve `entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]`?

Help me,Thanks

Comment: Why are you declaring the title as a maximum length of 30? Use `VARCHAR(255)` for anything by default, plus regular `INT`, which is `INT(11)` when expanded. Not sure where `INT(10)` came from.

Comment: I learned MySQL just yesterday....I don't know how to use it in a right way,just like English..Anyway,I got it ,thank you@ltay

Comment: No trouble. Just trying to give you a few pointers so you don't end up with even more confusion later on.

Comment: @tadman - none of what you said makes any sense to me. Check the manual then delete or amend as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Yes, it does returns number of queries because you are chaining two operations 1) getting cursor 2) calling execute in one and referring end result in `cur`

2) operation will result in integer value which gives number of rows get affected which is stored in `cur`